# Eclipse Indigo 3.7 Visual Page Editor throws XPCOM error

Tags: eclipse, xpcom, xulrunner

I'm using Eclipse Indigo SR2 for Java and Report Developers  with JBoss Tools 3.3.0 installed thru Software Manager on a Linux Xubuntu 64Bit 11.10 .

If I open a jsp or a html Page in JBoss Tools HTML Editor the Visual Editor throws an XPCOM error in Preview and in Visual/Source View.

Comment: So please split you question to question and answer, to acommodate the format of stackoverflow. And don't forget to accept your own answer later.

Answer (score 0):

This is user1430064's answer but he didn't post it as answer!
Piecing all information together I found there is a XULRunner embedded in the eclipse plugins directory (`.../eclipse-reporting-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64/plugins/org.mozilla.xulrunner.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.9.2.19pre/xulrunner`)  and setting eclipse to use this in eclipse.ini solves the problem  ...
I also deactivated the use of the Web Kit Browser but I don't know if this is necessary
(`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=false`)

```
-vm
/tmp/java/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit/libjvm.so
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms256m
-Xmx900m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/home/develop/lib/eclipse-reporting-indigo-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64/plugins/org.mozilla.xulrunner.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.9.2.19pre/xulrunner
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=false
```